# Loop incrementing operations for sugarcane replication

Tags: c#, report, gis

I'm creating an algorithm to calculate area for sugarcane replication.

I have an initial planted area of 5 hectares. These 5 hectares will be cut off when fully grown and then cloned in the proportion of 1:7 So my second area will have 35 Hectares (5*7)

The next areas will have a decreased propotion, because it gets lower at every cut.

So the third area will be (5*6) + (35*7)
forth area: (5*5) + (35*6) + (245 * 7) and so on. The user will input number for iteration and proportions to multiply.

doing by hand it would something like this:

```
area[0] = initialArea;
            area[1] = area[0] * proportion[0]; // = 35
            area[2] = area[0] * proportion[1] + area[1] * proportion[0];
            area[3] = (area[0] * proportion[2]) + (area[1] * proportion[1]) + (area[2] * proportion[0]);
            area[4] = (area[0] * proportion[3]) + (area[1] * proportion[2]) + (area[2] * proportion[1]) + (area[3] * proportion[0]);
            area[5] = (area[0] * proportion[4]) + (area[1] * proportion[3]) + (area[2] * proportion[2]) + (area[3] * proportion[1]) + (area[4] * proportion[0]);
```

Is there a way I can put this inside a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make that into a for-loop.

The loop for each iteration is:

```
for (int n = 0; n < iteration; n++)
{
    area[iteration] += area[n] * proportion[iteration - n - 1];
}
```

which you can wrap with the number of iterations:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= iterations; i++)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
    {
        area[i] += area[n] * proportion[i - n - 1];
    }
}
```

you will have to intialize with `area[0] = intialArea`. With input:

```
Console.Write("Enter inital area: ");
double initialArea = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter proportions, separate each proportion with spaces: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
double[] proportion = input.Split(' ').Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToArray();
int iterations = proportion.Length;
Console.WriteLine($"Using {iterations} iterations");

double[] area = new double[proportion.Length + 1];
area[0] = initialArea;

for (int i = 1; i <= iterations; i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Iteration = {i}: ");

    for (int n = 0; n < i; n++)
    {
        area[i] += area[n] * proportion[i - n - 1];

        Console.Write($"area[{n}] = {area[n]} ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```